# _wpnonce blank screen

Tags: wp-admin

this is killing me! I don't understand what is making _wpnonce and _wp_http_referer appearing in the url. If I manually delete them from the url, it is working, so this is the problem.

Even with all the plugins disabled and default theme it is still appearing on any action in wp-admin, for example when I search a post. As soon as _wpnonce is in the url, it will be a blank screen
 Tried all I could find on the internet, cheched wp-config.php, functions.php, searched for blank space...nothing.
 Tried wp debug - no error shows up
 in admin error log there is nothing.
 wordpress is installed in a folder, but it worked until now, and I made no changes.
  I took the code from wp-config-sample and used it, to make sure nothing else but the database info is added, but no luck there either.

What else can I do? how can I stop _wpnonce?

thanks!

Comment: See [`wp_nonce_field`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field) function.

Comment: thanks, but I did. I don't see anything that could help me. I see that if a nonce fails, an error message should be given, not blank screen. And I find no way to stop admin nonce. this should be WP default nonce

Comment: I suppose there is a call to [`check_ajax_referer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) in your code. But without seeing it one can't tell.

Comment: but what could call it? if this still happens without any plugin or custom theme

Comment: I do see -1 in the url as they say here "If $die is set to true, execution of the script will be stopped if the nonce cannot be verified, and the output will be '-1'."